# C++ LogFont Embed Into XPS

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts, xps

I am attempting to marry a couple of APIs together to facilitate XPS Printing.  As True Type Fonts are sometimes restricted on how they may be used it is suggested that you query the OS (Windows) for the license associated with a font.  The proscribed method I've found for doing that looks like this:

```
HDC hDC = CreateDC(L"DISPLAY", NULL, NULL, NULL);
// logfont is a valid instance of LOGFONTW
HGDIOBJ hfont = ::CreateFontIndirect(&logfont);
if (!SelectObject(hDC, hfont)) 
    return;
ULONG privstatus = 0; 
LONG ttStatus; 
ttStatus = TTGetEmbeddingType(hDC, &privstatus);
```

At this point ttStatus should be `E_NONE` if `TTGetEmbeddingType` succeeded and privstatus should be one of `{EMBED_PREVIEWPRINT, EMBED_EDITABLE, EMBED_INSTALLABLE, EMBED_NOEMBEDDING}`.  I had this example working Friday.  Today when I run my executable TTGetEmbeddingType returns `0x0A (E_NOTATRUETYPEFONT)` instead of `E_NONE`.  Wat?  Am I missing something fundamental about the OS's ability to determine whether a font can be embedded?

Comment: You've got something else going on. That's a pretty fundamental error that says something's seriously hosed with your app or your environment. And I wouldn't trust the error to be correct anyway. It's not even listed as one of the errors that family of functions can return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message text you quoted ("*The environment is incorrect*") belongs to the `ERROR_BAD_ENVIRONMENT` system error code, which has a numeric value of 10 (0x0A).  However, `TTGetEmbeddingType()` does not return a system error code.  The [`TTGetEmbeddingType()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145151.aspx) states:

> If successful, returns E_NONE.
>
> This function reads the embedding privileges stored in the font and transfers the privileges to pulPrivStatus.
>
> **Otherwise, returns an error code described in [Embedding-Function Error Messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144829.aspx).**

If you look at the actual definitions in `T2embapi.h`, a return value of `0x000A` is `E_NOTATRUETYPEFONT`

> The specified font is not a TrueType font.

Comment: The fonts in use are variants of Courier New, Arial, and OCR-A/B.  If I simply ignore the return value of TTGetEmbeddingType and use the fonts normally they embed in my XPS Document without complaint.

Comment: @g.d.d.c: Clearly `TTGetEmbeddingType()` does not believe the font is a TrueType font. Perhaps `CreateFontIndirect()` is not returning the font you think it is (your example is not validating the result).

Comment: That's where my confusion (and hence, the question) comes from.  Literally less than 48 hours ago the samples I was testing were working, but today they are not, though if I simply ignore what appears to be an erroneous return value the program completes the document creation successfully.  I've reviewed source changes (there aren't any relevant ones), double-checked that no updates took place, etc.  The fonts _work_ in the XPS Document.

Comment: Again, you are not checking the result of `CreateFontIndirect()`. Does it return NULL? If not, does `GetObject()` return the correct details about the font you are expecting? Just because you ask `CreateFontIndirect()` for a particular font does not guarantee you will get that font: "*If [CreateFontIndirect] fails to find an exact match, it provides an alternative whose characteristics match as many of the requested characteristics as possible.*" maybe you are getting a replacement font that is not really a TrueType font. Are you populating your source `LOGFONT` manually, or querying it?